# Does anyone know any service discovery library that can work with WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, service-discovery

I have some WebApi services which I would like to use ad-hoc style service discovery on. Is there any off the shelf libraries that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for UDDI as far as I know. And by the way, UDDI is dead.

This is an area not quite developed as much. As you can see even [programmableweb](http://www.programmableweb.com/) uses an RSS feed for discovery.

Comment: I actually wasn't looking at UDDI but WS-Discovery. Still...now I am interested...why did UDDI die?